# How can I automatically push after committing in Git?

Tags: git, githooks, git-push, post-commit-hook

How do I set Git to automatically push to a remote
repository (including automatically providing my passphrase) after each commit to the local repository?

Comment: What protocol are you pushing over?  If it's prompting for password, I assume that this is either SSH or HTTP.

Comment: Also, it's always helpful with git questions to at least mention what operating system you are using.

Comment: I question the wisdom of such a set up. This removes any ability to reorganize your changes into a different set of commits (rebasing, especially). I make too many mistakes for a set up like this to end up being useful for me.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

First, make sure that you can push manually without providing your password.  If you are pushing over HTTP or HTTPS, that will be a case of either [creating a `.netrc` file with the login details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password) or [adding your username and password into the URL for the remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093558/using-github-behind-a-firewall-without-ssh-access/5093726#5093726).  If you're using SSH, you can either create a keypair where the private key doesn't have a password, or [use `ssh-agent` to cache your private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh/1595863#1595863).

Then you should create an executable (`chmod +x`) file in `.git/hooks/post-commit` that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
git push origin master
```

... customizing that line if you want to push to a remote other than `origin`, or push a branch other than `master`.  Make sure that you make that file executable.

Comment: Couldn't make ssh-agent remember my passphrase, so had to make it empty. Hope my wife won't hack my account :)

Comment: Speaking of customization, what if I want to push some but not all branches in this manner? For example, I want to auto-push only the branches that have a corresponding remote branch noted in `.git/config` with the prefix `feature/xy/`.

Comment: git push --all origin

Comment: chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit

Comment: If you don't want to store the password then also this  approach works very well. Only thing after every commit you have to type the password.

Answer (score 40):

If you start using more than the master branch, you might want to automatically push the current branch. My hook (`.git/hooks/post-commit`) looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

branch_name=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
retcode=$?
non_push_suffix="_local"

# Only push if branch_name was found (my be empty if in detached head state)
if [ $retcode -eq 0 ] ; then
    #Only push if branch_name does not end with the non-push suffix
    if [[ $branch_name != *$non_push_suffix ]] ; then
        echo
        echo "**** Pushing current branch $branch_name to origin [i4h post-commit hook]"
        echo
        git push origin $branch_name;
    fi
fi
```

It pushes the current branch, if it can determine the branch name with git symbolic-ref.

"[How to get current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-current-branch-name-in-git)" deals with this and other ways to get the current branch name.

An automatic push for every branch can be disturbing when working in task branches where you expect some [sausage making](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/#sausage) to happen (you won't be able to rebase easily after pushing). So the hook will not push branches that end with a defined suffix (in the example "_local").

Comment: For the first line, i had to use `#!/bin/sh` to make it work. Otherwise it kept saying: `error: cannot run .git/hooks/post-commit: No such file or directory`. Thank you, I like your solution best.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @oyalhi , I updated the shebang line in the answer. It should port better now!

Comment: hello i get this error: .git/hooks/post-commit: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
.git/hooks/post-commit: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Hey, indeed there was a lost backtick. I updated the answer, please try again

Comment: Why `#!/usr/bin/env bash`? What is the meaning of it (what is it supposed to do)? Is it to use Bash instead of [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#Dash) (`sh`)? On what system? [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus)? Why is it different from the default `#!/usr/sh`?

Answer (score 14):

Create a file named "post-commit" in the *.git/hooks* directory with the contents "git push". Though if you want to automatically provide a password, a modification will be needed.

Comment: What kind of modification? Perhaps extend the answer (and/or point to some reference or Stack Overflow post)?

Comment: Besides, the file post-commit needs to be executable

Answer (score 3):

This [git-autopush](https://github.com/chopmo/git-autopush/blob/master/git-autopush.sh) script allows you to setup a post-commit hook, similar to what has been recommended in "[How configure automatic pushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839439/how-configure-automatic-pushing)".
But for the passphrase, you need to [run a `ssh-agent`](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/).

Comment: There is no need for `ssh-agent`, just use another passphrase-less `git`-only `ssh`-key:  `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_pushonly`.  `echo $'\nHost pushonly\nHostname DESTINATION\nIdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_pushonly\n' >> ~/.ssh/config`.  On `DESTINATION` configure `git-shell` as shown in https://superuser.com/a/444899/72223 using pubkey from `~/.ssh/id_pushonly.pub`.  The needed `git`-URL is something like `git@pushonly:path/to/repo.git`.  To debug: `ssh git@pushonly COMMAND` must run `git-shell -c COMMAND` on `DESTINATION`.  For `COMMAND` see `man git-shell`

Comment: @Tino Thank you. Why are you using the digital signature scheme `-t ed25519`? I use generally `-t rsa`, although recently I have to add `-m PEM` to `ssh-keygen` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53729009/6309).

Comment: @Tino I understand rsa is slower, less secure (if its length is lower than 2048 bits: https://bagja.net/blog/upgrade-ssh-key-to-ed25519.html), but I deal at work with older openssh servers which might not interpret correctly an ed255519 signature.

Comment: I primarily use `ed25519` because it gives short and handy lines for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Also it is very interesting [what DJB writes about ed255519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/):  Secure against side channels (Spectre), less CPU, etc.  BTW, when dealing with old `sshd`s, I usually create a special key for them and then configure this in `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Bash script for Git to automatically `push` to a remote repository

1. Automatically check [ssh-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549332/how-to-check-if-ssh-agent-is-already-running-in-bash/57351920#57351920)
2. Automatically send passphrase using [expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository/56304600#56304600)
3. Usage is simply: `cd /path/to/your/repository` and then `push`

Add this script to a file, for example, `$HOME/.ssh/push`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check connection
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
[[ "$?" == 2 ]] && eval `ssh-agent` > /dev/null

# Check if Git config is configured
if [ ! $(git config user.name) ]
then
    git config --global user.name <user_name>
    git config --global user.email <user_email>
fi

# Check if expect is installed
if [[ ! $(dpkg -l | grep expect) ]]
then
    apt-get update > /dev/null
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends apt-utils expect > /dev/null
fi

# Check identity
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
[[ "$?" == 1 ]] && expect $HOME/.ssh/agent > /dev/null

# Clean and push the repository
REMOTE=$(git remote get-url origin)
URL=git@github.com:${REMOTE##*github.com/}
[[ $REMOTE == "http"* ]] && git remote set-url origin $URL
git add . && git commit -m "test automatically push to a remote repo"
git status && git push origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) --force
```

Link it to the `/bin` directory, so it can be called by just the `push` command:

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/.ssh/push /bin/push
chmod +x /bin/push
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are simple instructions for pushing/pulling without providing passphrase over SSH for people using Linux and Windows ([Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway))

On your client:

1. Check out if you have SSH keys generated:

   ```
    $ ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub; ls ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
    /c/Users/Cermo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  <-- I have RSA key
    ls: cannot access '/c/Users/Cermo/.ssh/id_dsa.pub': No such file or directory
   ```
2. If you don't have any key (two "ls: cannot access ..." lines), generate a new one. If you have any of the keys, skip this step.

   ```
   $ ssh-keygen.exe
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Cermo/.ssh/id_rsa):
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): <-- press Enter
   Enter same passphrase again: <-- press Enter
   ```
3. Copy your key to remote server from which you want to pull or push using git:

   ```
   $ ssh-copy-id user_name@server_name
   /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to
   filter out any that are already installed
   /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you
   are prompted now it is to install the new keys
   user_name@server_name's password:

   Number of key(s) added: 1

   Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'user_name@server_name'"
   and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
   ```

Note: You will have to provide a password during this operation. After that, your pull/push operations won't request a password.

Note 2: You have to log in to the server using *user_name* at least once before using this procedure (the home directory, to which SSH keys are copied, is created during the first login).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Husky, it will overwrite your `post-commit` hooks file by default.

We're using this command in package.json to auto-rebase-and-push any commits to master.  (First run `yarn add --dev git-branch-is`.)

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
     "post-commit": "git-branch-is master && git rebase origin master && git push origin master"`
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Git file: *commit.sh*

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   cd c:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/nalms/src
   git add --all
   timestamp() {
     date +"at %H:%M:%S on %d/%m/%Y"
   }
   git commit -am "Regular auto-commit $(timestamp)"
   git push origin master
   ```
2. Open window task scheduler
3. Create new task
4. *General* → name the task
5. Go to the trigger section and enable the task scheduler
6. Press the <kbd>Done</kbd> button

Comment: What is *"window task scheduler"*? Is this on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)? Do you mean [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)? Or something else? You could also provide a screenshot to supplement the description (perhaps even [free-hand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) (no joke)). Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67125538/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).