# Git client with "autopush"?

Tags: windows, git, client

Does a git client exist (preferably for windows) with autopush functionality?
As in automatically pushes to origin/master on commit.

I am aware this goes against the whole git methodology and can be achieved with hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of (and there aren't that many clients for Git on Windows to begin with: [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) being the main one coming to mind).

Setting up a dedicated hook for that feature remains your best option (as in "[How to automatically push after committing in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git)"). I know hat this is what you were aware of, but I just pointed out that I didn't see that feature directly implemented in a Git client.