# Deploying when push to git

Tags: php, git, deployment, version-control

I need to push the code automatically when there is a push in my repository. Until now i used DeployHQ, but recently i moved to a new hosting company which is using FTPS for file transfer. But DeployHQ is not supporting that. So please suggest any ways or tricks to use DeployHQ over ftps protocol or any scripts to accomplish this. Please help.

Comment: Are you using GitHib for your code hosting?

Comment: @NBhargav No. I'm using bitbucket

Comment: Okay and where are you deploying your code?

Comment: @NBhargav I'm deploying to my website (I hosted in bigrock)

Comment: Seems like ftp is supported on BigRock. http://manage.bigrock.in/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq962.html

Comment: If ftp doesn't work, you may try SSH to deploy your site using DeployHQ and if you are using Linux hosting on BigRock then enable SSH access. http://manage.bigrock.in/kb/answer/1817

Comment: @NBhargav Regarding FTP, they are referring the term FTP to refer FTPS only. I will give a try regarding SSH.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45267/discussion-between-n-bhargav-and-udhay)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically push after committing in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git)

Comment: @guerda This is issue is specific to BigRock and DeployHQ services used for deployments. Even though it is a similar issue, that post won't really help fix this one.

Comment: @NBhargav Sorry, I misunderstood. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So enabling SSH on your hosting panel (BigRock) and configuring the same on DeployHQ seems to resolve your issue.