# When I commit to a local git repository, I want it to automatically push to the repository on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a local git repository. I commit a change using `git commit -a` and it updates the local repository. So far so good.

I would like it so when I do this it also automatically pushes to my remote repository on Bitbucket. How do I do this?

Comment: I think that this answer will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git

Comment: It is possible but not really a good idea. What if there are upstream changes? If you push automatically without pulling those changes down your push will fail.