# How to sync data between local git repo and heroku remote repo..?

Tags: git, heroku, automation

I want to sync data between local git repo and heroku git how can i do that.
and i want to automate this whenever i want commit changes to local repo it will automatically pushed to heroku ?

Comment: I think its already answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically push after committing in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git)