# What does git sync do in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

What commands are actually run when you *Synchronise Changes* in Visual Studio Code?

[image: git sync in vscode]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the [VSCode online help](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol):

> Given that your repository is connected to some remote and that your checked out branch has an upstream link to a branch in that remote, VS Code offers you useful actions to push, pull and sync that branch (**the latter will run a pull command followed by a push command**).

It appears that if you run synchronize changes on a given branch, it will do the following:

```
git pull origin someBranch
git push origin someBranch
```

Per the comment by @FelikZ one way to make `pull --rebase` the default behavior for `git pull` would be to configure your `.gitconfig` file by adding the following:

```
[pull]
    rebase = true
```

Then, when the VSCode plugin issues a `git pull`, it should use the rebase strategy by default.  If you follow the above link and scroll to the section "Git patch/diff mode," you will see a screen capture which actually shows configuring Git for pulling via rebase.

**Update:** As of v1.28 there is now a `git.rebaseWhenSync` setting. From the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_always-rebase-when-running-sync):

> The git.rebaseWhenSync setting will let you configure the Sync command to always use rebase instead of merge when running.

Comment: I could have sworn there was more to it, such as stashing pending changes before pushing :)

Comment: Is there a way to change it behaviour, so it will `pull --rebase` instead of just pull?

Comment: @FelikZ I updated my answer.  I think you can update your `.gitconfig` file to use rebase by default when pulling.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for a response. I did some search and have found, that its actually will be released in VSCode itself soon (November 2017), [see this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/31416) !

Comment: Updated answer to include new `git.rebaseWhenSync` setting!

Comment: If you want to do this on all branches, you can grab [hub](https://hub.github.com/) and run `hub sync` (or `alias git="hub"` in your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` to run `git sync`)

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Code sync sequence : PUSH + PULL
[screen shot from VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMCCu.png)

Visual Studio 2019 sync sequence : PULL + PUSH
[screen shoot from Visual Studio 2019 documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ6M4.png)