# Git Rebase Visual Studio Code: What is the difference between the three git rebase options in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, rebase

Can someone please explain to me the differences between these options for git rebase through visual studio code?
[image: Visual Studio Code Rebase Options]

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't exactly rebase options.  Compare to what happens when you type in a Google query:

how **many weeks in a year**
how **many ounces in a gallon**
how **to screenshot on windows**
Howie Mandel
Howl's Moving Castle

Your question is a bit like asking why these options popped up for `howitzer` in the middle of the question.

The screenshot you show—by the way, don't use screenshots if at all possible, but if you do, inline them (I did that for you here)—have brought up two basic Git commands:

- `git pull`, which simply runs two commands for you—`git fetch`, followed by one of `git merge` or `git rebase`—and this gave you a way to invoke the use-rebase-as-the-second-command-style `git pull`; and
- `git rebase`, which *is* the `git rebase` command (and needs more information).

The third option you got was to run a VSCode-specific thing that VSCode calls "git sync".  This is not a *Git* command at all: instead, it's a sort of VSCode action that runs two Git commands for you, namely `git pull` followed by `git push`.  The `pull` itself *is* a Git command, which then runs the two Git commands (fetch, plus whatever second one you've chosen by configuration, although in this case perhaps the selector overrides the configuration and makes the second command be `git rebase` anyway).  See [What does git sync do in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36878344/1256452) for more about this.

Comment: Thank you this was a very good explanation! Sorry for the incorrect formatting, this is my second time posting

Comment: I would upvote but I don't have a good enough reputation yet lol