# How To Set Up Auto Updating Git

Tags: github, backup

I'm using Github to store my projects, and would like to know if there is a way for me to get my repository to automatically update in real time.

To clarify what I mean, I'm currently using the good old "git clone" "git add" "git commit" "git push" technique, but it's becoming rather tedious.

What mechanism can I put in place to achieve that?

Comment: Please concretely describe what automatism you are expecting. Commits to be automatically pushed? I don't see how an automatism in the the are of "git clone" and "git add" would lead to reasonable behavior/results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the push side, you can use a local `.git/hooks/post-commit` that includes:

```
#!/bin/sh
git push origin master
```

(assuming here you are pushing from `master`: you have other options at "[How to automatically push after committing in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7925850/6309)")

---

If you want a local repo always up-to-date with a remote GitHub repo, you can setup a [webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) which will listen for push events and automatically pull for you.

See for instance [this webhook](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/619858) (or [this one](https://gist.github.com/phedoreanu/11321236)):

```
<?php
// Use in the "Post-Receive URLs" section of your GitHub repo.
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_GITHUB_EVENT'] == 'push') {
  shell_exec( 'cd /srv/www/git-repo/ && git reset --hard HEAD && git pull' );
}
?>hi
```

The [OP NodziGames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6419293/nodzigames) decided [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740647/how-to-set-up-auto-updating-git/37741396?noredirect=1#comment62990591_37741396) to go for a more "on demand" approach:

> create a Makefile where I can clone, add new files, commit and push via a single command.

Comment: Hey VonC, thanks for the answer. The kind of automatism I was looking for is one that updates in real time as I type. I realized that it would be a bad idea after reading your comment, so instead I decided to create a Makefile where I can clone, add new files, commit and push via a single command. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @NodziGames Sure. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.