# Pushing from local machine to git remote repo and production machine

Tags: windows, git, github

I'm attempting to setup a git repo for a project but I want to create a streamline push process for windows machines. Currently, I have to commit from the local to the git repo and then RDP into the production server and do a pull. I want to be able to commit the master branch from my local machine and have that automatically be pulled to the production server.

I've looked around for a good bit and all I can find are linux solutions that I can't or don't understand how to implement. Is this possible for Windows? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: How about simply scheduling a pull at fitting intervals?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically push after committing in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git)