# git commit & push in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How can I configure IntelliJ to commit and push in a single task (preferably a keyboard shortcut)?

When developing I'm always on a work-in-progress branch and use git commit nearly as often as saving the file. When I'm finished with a task I squash the work done and split it up into logical commits.

But I frequently change my working environment and when I forgot to push I don't have access to the latest commits :-(

Therefore I'd like IntelliJ to git commit & push at once. I know how to do it on the command line but I'd prefer to do it from inside IntelliJ as I'm working there most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the additional contexts on the 'Submit / Commit button in the commit dialog. [See 'Submit / Commit button' here.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/commit-changes-dialog.html)

The 'automatic' option would be to add a post-commit hook as [detailed in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7925891/2344348)

Comment: Wow that context menu was so obvious, I didn't even notice it's content