# On commit master , update code in multiple repositories

Tags: git, gitlab

On committing my master branch to my Git repository, I need to update that latest code to multiple other repositories.
How can I do this?

```
git commit -u origin master
```

eg: if I have repository 1,2 and 3.
If I push my code to master branch only in repository 1, automatically code should be updated in master branch of repository2 and 3.

Comment: Do you mean update other branches in the same repository?

Comment: No, updating master branch in other repositories...

Comment: Are those other repositories have a different origin than the one you're committing to?

Comment: i have updated my question please check.....

Comment: I think am looking for git hooks..Can anybody suggest a good reference for this?Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget you can [push to multiple repos in one step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/6309)

```
git remote add all git://original/repo.git
git remote set-url --add --push all git://another/repo.git
git remote set-url --add --push all git://original/repo.git

git push all master
```

A pure post-commit hook push solution would be "[How to automatically push after committing in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7925850/6309)".
For instance, [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28042939/6309) from [i4h](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3337068/i4h):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

branch_name=`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` 
retcode=$?
non_push_suffix="_local"

# Only push if branch_name was found (my be empty if in detached head state)
if [ $retcode = 0 ] ; then
    #Only push if branch_name does not end with the non-push suffix
    if [[ $branch_name != *$non_push_suffix ]] ; then
        echo
        echo "**** Pushing current branch $branch_name to origin [i4h_mobiles post-commit hook]"
        echo
        git push origin $branch_name;
    fi
fi
```

It will push any branch except the one named `xxx_local` (in order to avoid pushing those branches when multiple intermediate commits are done before you are ready for said commits to be pushed).

Comment: Thank you..I think am looking for git hooks..Can you suggest a good reference for this?

Comment: @Dev The point is: you don't need Git hooks. But if you do, then a  good reference is https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7925850/6309. I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Could you please share the a sample hook script for pushing code to another repo in post-commit...Thanks

Comment: i have tried adding this, ==>  !/bin/sh
git push production master; to pre-receive file but not working..

Comment: @Dev No this is a post-commit client side hook, not a pre-receive server side hook

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps correctly:

If you want to push code in one repository:

**Step1**: git add -A (this will add all files to git)

**Step2**: git commit -m "First commit"

**Step3**: git remote add origin **(first repo url)**

**Step4**: git push -u origin master

If you want to push code to multiple repositories

Follow above two Steps

Then

**Step 3**: git remote add alt **(second remote url)**

**Step 4**: git push alt master

Comment: Thanks, actually the code should be automatically pushed to other repos, if i push to my master branch only...is your suggestion suits my scenario?Thanks

Comment: Thank you..I think am looking for git hooks..Can you suggest a good reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may using git hook to do so.

First, locate your hook folder:

```
git config --list
#...
#core.hookspath=~/shared-git-hooks
```

Or set it using the following command:

```
git config core.hookspath ~/shared-git-hooks
```

Create a hook file contains scripts

```
touch ~/shared-git-hooks/post-commit

#post-commit file
git push ...
```

After set it, once you commit will run the script inside post-commit.

You may see more details for git hook here:
https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Hope it can help.

---

The script may look like:

```
#This script will push master to all existing remote
#git remote add repo2 https://github.com/repo2.git
#git remote add repo3 https://github.com/repo3.git
for remote in $(git remote); do git push $remote master; done;
```

Also please note that if you want to trigger it when push then need to use `pre-push` hook instead of `post-commit`

One more thing, if you want only doing this stuff on specific project / repository, then you may need to check the project location first.

```
if [ "$(pwd)" == "/your/project/path" ]; then
    for remote in $(git remote); do git push $remote master; done;
fi
```

Comment: I updated the script for your reference, hope it can help :)