# Is there a way for Jenkins or Crontab to push commits automatically to a GitHub repo?

Tags: linux, github, jenkins, cron, push

I've been trying to push commits created with a simple shell script:

```
cd $dir
git add . && git commit -m "Test commit" &&
git push --all origin
```

The script does the job perfectly. Yet Crontab is stuck at making commits locally and Jenkins is getting 'Permission denied' when accessing a local git folder even if I assign Jenkins a group that owns the folder.

I tried Jenkins jobs with Execute shell either with the code or the path to the script. Any help would much appreciated.

Comment: You have to add git creadentials to git, e.g. as shown here (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-git-credentials-in-jenkins/) and use this to push commits.

Comment: It will break on first merge conflict

Comment: Added git creds as advised. Still permission denied when cd to a directory and fatal from git (not a git repo) as well. Any plugin to push commits available?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that Jenkins goes back to the original workspace to run each command. So when you run `cd $dir`, the script will switch to `$dir`, but once you start the `git add...` command, it will go back to your workspace directory. To prevent this, either chain the commands together:

```
cd $dir && git add . && git commit -m "Test commit" && git push --all origin
```

or use [dir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) to wrap the git commands so that they always run in that specific directory.

Comment: Chaining does not work either. Do I need a jenkinsfile to use dir?

Comment: @HarrierPanels Yes, `dir` works on pipeline as code. But first look at why chaining doesn't work. Add a `pwd` command after `cd $dir` and see if you are in the correct directory. If so, then the problem is something else.

Comment: cd $dir gets Permission denied

Comment: Solved for cron. Created a hook to push automatically after a commit is done by cron, the solution is here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-can-i-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git

Now gonna check it with jenkins.

Comment: Added a local node to Jenkins. It now commits an pushes by shell commands, no hook or plugins used. Solved!

Comment: @HarrierPanels Consider answering your own question with detailed information on how you fixed it for anyone else who comes upon this problem

Answer (score 0):

As advised by [@M B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730626/m-b) summarizing:

*Crontab*:

For the cron commits to be pushed automatically:

Add a hook file to your git directory:
[How can I automatically push after committing in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-can-i-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git)

*Jenkins*:

To commit and push automatically add a node. I also added to a sudoers file by `sudo visudo`:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I have also assigned a safe directory:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory /path/to/your/git/dir
```

EDIT: Just tested with Amazon EC2 Plugin, after cloning the repo on an EC2 instance use:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://ghp_TOKEN@github.com/USER/REPO.git
git add . && git commit -m "COMMIT" && git push --all origin
```

And these 3 also work for Crontab and Terraform (no other settings needed).

Hope this helps.