# GitHub Windows client behind proxy

Tags: github, proxy, github-for-windows

I'm trying to get the GitHub client for Windows working. I am on a corporate [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) x64 computer behind a corporate proxy and firewall.

Following various other posts and experimenting with multiple combinations of environment variables and configuration variables, I have found the only way to get cloning and push updates to work is by using the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable, including my full corporate domain user ID and password.

This is unacceptable from a security standpoint. Is there another way to get this to work?

#### Additional notes:

The following worked:

- Add an environment variable called `HTTPS_PROXY` with the value `http://[domain]\[userid]:[password]@someproxy.mycorp.com:8080`

The following did **not** work:

- Omitting user id and password from `HTTPS_PROXY` variable
- Using an environment variable called `HTTP_PROXY` (no `S`)
- Adding the `http.proxy` variable to the global configuration file (`.gitconfig`)
- Adding the `https.proxy` variable to the global configuration file

In all cases, the GitHub *client* still does not recognize the proxy: The content of the file `TheLog.txt` *always* shows the following on startup:

```
[time]|INFO|thread:4|GitHub.Helpers.StartupLogger|Proxy information: (None)
[time]|INFO|thread:4|GitHub.Helpers.StartupLogger|Couldn't fetch creds for proxy
```

And it is followed by the output of several failed proxy authentication attempts, all of which indicate "Credentials are missing."

Comment: Adding the environment variable did the trick for me, but it is an unacceptable solution, as it exposes my domain/password to any application with access to the environment variables.

Comment: http://jacobbenson.com/?p=302#sthash.DzPYdGUU.dpbs explains that this is caused by the gui (which correctly uses the windows set proxy) calls msysgit behind the scenes for the git commands.
msysgit uses libcurl for http requests, which doesn't use the windows proxy settings. There is work ongoing to fix this in several areas including with libgit2sharp at https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Add these entries to your '.gitconfig' file in your user directory (go to %USERPROFILE%):

```
[http]
    proxy = http://<proxy address>:<proxy port>

[https]
    proxy = https://<proxy address>:<proxy port>
```

And if you don't want to store your password in plaintext, I would use a local proxy forwarder like CNTLM which allows you to direct all traffic through it and can store the passwords hashed.

---

*Unlike the original question, **if you don't care if your password is in plain text** add these:*

```
[http]
    proxy = http://<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>

[https]
    proxy = https://<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>
```

Comment: see edufinn answer if you need authorization against the proxy: proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<corporate proxy>:<port>

Comment: @JanHommes The original question was specifically asking about how to do it without storing the password in plaintext

Comment: @Sogger If my password include "@" character, how should i configure the password, thanks for your help.

Comment: @coastline http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password

Comment: CNTLM was a fantastic suggestion.  +1

Comment: @Sogger For me this didn't help. I need to write my System username and password in there, right?

Comment: @AndroidNFC You need to use your proxy credentials, whatever those are for you

Comment: If you are using CNTLM, make sure you point the proxy to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, as suggested. In Windows, it appears that localhost points first to the IPv6 address, which CNTLM doesn't listen to. As such, git will wait until the timeout (several minutes) before switching to the IPv4 address.

Comment: I just added another answer which expands on this to show how it can be done without CNTLM or storing the credentials. (As long as your proxy server supports turning off the AUTH requirement for *.github.com)

Comment: It worked well for me. I made it permanent for my local repo settings since I always access this repo behind the proxy. I made `git config http.proxy http://<url>:port` and `git config https.proxy http://<url>:port`.

Comment: I'm on a corporate Windows 10 (1803) network, and passwords in plain text is not acceptable. I added my username and password for our proxy-servers to `Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials` as _Windows Credentials_ (instead of using _CNTLM_). Together with the above solution for `.gitconfig` it works for me.

Answer (score 15):

I tried everything in the previous answers, but I didn't succeed. The only thing that helped me was [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

Install it and run `cntlm -H`, then authenticate to the corporate proxy, edit the *cntlm.ini* file with the output of `cntlm`, and restart the windows service. Update file *.gitconfig* with:

```
[https] proxy = localhost:3128
[http] proxy = localhost:3128
```

Now cntlm will do all the authentication, and you'll be able to use GitHub (and Dropbox, btw) behind the corporate proxy. At least until the next password change :) (then do the `cntlm -H` stuff again)

Comment: If remote actions like git clone, fetch or pull take a very long time to complete, try switching the .gitconfig to:

    [https] proxy = 127.0.0.1:3128
    [http] proxy = 127.0.0.1:3128

Comment: restart what windows service?

Comment: @Mukus cntlm - it runs in service mode after installation, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I made the change, restarted it and it still does not work.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to make GitHub Shell work with our corporate proxy. I'm starting GitHub Shell and execute following command:

```
export http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<corporate proxy>:3128
```

I would really like to make GUI to work too. But I don't want to set the Windows global environment variable which contains my corporate credential information.

Strangely, GitHub GUI Client is able to connect to GitHub for user authentication, but the only problem is with cloning, pulling and pushing projects from and into GitHub. It seems like the problem is with the Git implementation. I was able to configure Git to run through our proxy without putting my credentials in the Git global settings and it was asking for my credentials while performing pull or push requests. But that was working only in Git Shell.

Comment: That's because probably GitHub authenticates internally with some component that pulls proxy info from the OS, possibly some SingleSignOn solution, while git itself does not. I have the same problem with SourceTree. I also found that when git works, it takes an impossibly long time to work, making SourceTree usage impossible.

Comment: This is likely because Github is trying to use the git port which is typically filtered as its not a common one for IT folks to see. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 8):

If you’re using GitHub for Windows in a corporate place, chances are high that you’re behind a big bad corporate firewall or proxy. GitHub for Windows doesn’t yet have the proxy parameters in its GUI for setting options.

To configure GitHub for Windows to use your corporate proxy, edit the *.gitconfig* file typically found at C:\Users<yourusername>.gitconfig or C:\Documents & Settings<yourusername>.gitconfig

Close GitHub for Windows; in file *.gitconfig*, just add:

```
[https]
proxy = proxy.yourcompany.com:port
```

Answer (score 4):

I've also run into this issue, and tried to dig into it a bit as well (disassembled the client).

The piece of code that generates the log messages we're seeing is as follows:

```cs
private static void LogProxyServerConfiguration()
{
    WebProxy defaultProxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
    string str = defaultProxy.Address != (Uri)null ? defaultProxy.Address.ToString() : "(None)";
    StartupLogger.log.Info((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Proxy information: {0}", str);
    try
    {
        if (defaultProxy.Credentials == null)
        {
            StartupLogger.log.Info((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Couldn't fetch creds for proxy", new object[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            NetworkCredential credential = defaultProxy.Credentials.GetCredential(GitHubClient.GitHubDotComUri, "Basic");
            StartupLogger.log.Info((IFormatProvider)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Proxy is authenticated: {0}", credential != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(credential.UserName));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StartupLogger.log.InfoException("Couldn't fetch creds for proxy", ex);
    }
}
```

So this block only logs the proxy information that's *setup in IE*. The log message appears to have no bearing on what we have setup in the config files or environmental variables.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know about your firewall, but my campus uses a proxy.

Do you use any Git GUI? I just noticed that you're using the GitHub client for Windows.

I am using [TortoiseGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit) and its very easy to set the proxy. Just right click anywhere, *TortoiseGit* → *Network*, enable the proxy server and set the server address, username, and password. Done.

As far as I remember, TortoiseGit will also works out-of-the-box with GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to set the proxy in GitHub:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<username>:<pass>@<ip>:<port>
git config --global https.proxy http://<username>:<pass>@<ip>:<port>
```

Here in my college we don't have usernames and passwords, so if our college IP address is 172.16.10.10 and
the port is 8080:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://172.16.10.10:8080
git config --global https.proxy http://172.16.10.10:8080
```

P.S.: I would recommend using this method to set proxy as things will fall into place as you will learn further. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this blog](http://hwiechers.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-use-git-behind-proxy-requiring.html) to be useful. It describes [ntlmaps](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmaps/) proxy. It's probably less secure, but worked smoothly. I couldn't get cntlm working.

Comment: That isn't sufficient. Can you summarise here?

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. The entire `hwiechers.blogspot.com` blog was removed.

Answer (score 1):

For us, the solution involved two different things. First, as described in [Sogger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153450/github-windows-client-behind-proxy/18618941#18618941), you need to add the entries to your `.gitconfig` file, located in `%USERPROFILE%`.

```
[http]
    proxy = http://<proxy address>:<proxy port>

[https]
    proxy = https://<proxy address>:<proxy port>
```

Second, (and this was the missing piece for us,) you need to configure an exception on the proxy server to allow ***non-authenticated*** proxy traffic to `*.github.com`

In iPrism, it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is not so much the proxy, but the *authentication*. Bypassing the authentication requirement allows the needed communication to clone and work with projects using the GitHub desktop client.

Also note that this approach **did not require storing proxy credentials** in the `.gitconfig` file.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to **force Git or GitHub client to bypass the proxy (use the direct connection)**, just set the proxy URI in the `.gitconfig` to an empty string. You'll probably have to edit the file manually, but I didn't manage to persuade the `git config` command to set the value of a configuration directive to an empty string (tried `git config --global http.proxy ""`).

So just add the following lines to the `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[http]
    proxy = ""
[https]
    proxy = ""
```

Comment: This will not work if you are in a corporate environment and there is no way to bypass the proxy.

Comment: @SteveScott Sure, but for me, it was the only way to get through/around the corporate proxy (as we didn't have proxy authentication credentials). It's probably a network misconfiguration, because it doesn't make a sense to enforce a proxy that you can bypass, but for me, it was important that I can configure my tools so they're able to connect to the internet in such environment.