# Github: failed to clone a repository

Tags: github, repository, git-clone, github-for-windows

I installed Github for Windows and try to clone a repository but then I constantly receive the error: "failed to clone the repository abc"

I checked the log and this is an extract:

> System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not
>   supported.
>          at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess
>   access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean
>   needFullPath)
>          at GitHub.Helpers.CommandHandler.SelectRepositoryByPath(String path)

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem is the computer is under proxy. I need to proxy to the config file and it works.

So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153450/github-windows-client-behind-proxy?answertab=oldest#tab-top) answer help.